# Converting DateTime from ISO_INSTANT to seconds from midnight

Tags: java, arrays, datetime, gps

I'm new to Java and DateTime formats in general, and I'm supposed to convert GPS data from CSV files. **My question is how this is done for the format I'm working with.** The data points I'm getting from the GPS data is in the format as follows:

> time,lat,lon,elevation

I have split up the different data points and put them in a string array, and I'm supposed to convert the data points to either integer or double arrays, as follows:

```
public void convert() {
int n = timesstr.length; //Amount of data points
times = new int[n]; //Array for time in seconds (int)       
latitudes = new double[n]; //Array for latitudes (double)
longitudes = new double[n]; //Array for longitudes (double)
elevations = new double[n]; //Array for elevations (double)
}
```

I'm planning to do a for-loop, converting the elements in the arrays one after one. Now the problem is how I'm supposed to convert the time from the data point to seconds from midnight, as the data point for time is formatted as ISO_INSTANT, e.g.

> 2017-08-13T08:52:26.000Z

How should I go about parsing and converting the data points from ISO_INSTANT to seconds from midnight? According to the information I got, the data point

> 2017-08-13T08:52:26.000Z

Should give the integer 31946 after conversion, as in 31956 seconds past midnight.

Comment: Have you read the [Javadoc for `java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2017-08-13T08:52:26.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME).get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
```

Or as pointed out by [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) you can do:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-08-13T08:52:26.000Z").get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
```

> is shorter, and more lenient. It even supports Daylight Savings Time, if a time zone other that Z is given. - Andreas

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-08-13T08:52:26.000Z").get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY)` is shorter, and more lenient. It even supports Daylight Savings Time, if a time zone other that `Z` is given.

Comment: Unless it’s a requirement to recognize a named time zone (such as Asia/Jayapura), I’d prefer `OffsetDateTime` over `ZonedDateTime`. A third option would be `Instant.parse("2017-08-13T08:52:26.000Z").atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);`.